# how to set dropdownlist height and how to show dropdownlist's list always downward display

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

How can I set a dropdownlist control's height in C#?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
cbo.Attributes.Add("style", "height: 50%");
```

And, how can I make sure a dropdownlist's list is always dropped down rather than up?

---

At last I got it..

```
 cbo.Height = new Unit("250px");
```

I can set dropdownlist height with above code.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "C#.NET"

Comment: So what is this? please explain me! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334647%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: It is C#. And the correct link would be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx, unless you're stuck using .NET 1.1.

Comment: aww thanks! wrong in my question? I should use in "C#" ? not "C#.NET" ? Thanks Thanks!!

Comment: That's correct. The name is "C#".

Comment: @JohnSaunders let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1463/discussion-between-redsdevils-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to "How to set height" is:

```
   cbo.Height = new Unit("250px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily you can increase the font size of the items in the dropdown control, this will set height. Will try to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of a dropdownlist as follows:

```
combobox1.DropDownHeight = 106;
```

Make sure that the `DrawMode` attribute of the combobox is set to `Normal`. This way it's items can be populated without much difficulty.