# how to set size of select dropdown in css

Tags: html, css

I want to limit the select dropdown height but using size property view is changed. Is there any option to set the height of the dropdown list of a select element?

Comment: Try this link. It will be helpfull.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659457/how-to-set-dropdownlist-height-and-how-to-show-dropdownlists-list-always-downwa][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659457/how-to-set-dropdownlist-height-and-how-to-show-dropdownlists-list-always-downwa

Comment: Have a look at this, it is not possible for most browsers as it is native: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534738/1238244

Comment: The only way to achieve it I believe is to use a mimic element which sits over the top of the dropdown. These are useful if you want to skin a native input element. But it does involve some work. this is one I particularly like http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/update there is another I prefer but I cannot remember the name now.

Comment: This one: http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Answer (score 0):

to set the height of the drop down `select` node you will need to set height property in style.

SAMPLE CODE BELOW:

```
<select id="ddl_Country" name="Country" style="height: 50px; border: 1px solid black">
    <option id ="01" selected="selected" >INDIA</option>
    <option id ="02" >AUSTRALIA</option>
    <option id ="03" >SINGAPORE</option>
    <option id ="04" >NEW ZEALAND</option>
    <option id ="05" >RUSSIA</option>
    <option id ="06" >JAPAN</option>    
</select>
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6B47/)

in order to increase the height of the list `option` tag in select you will need to create a custom drop down using `<DIV>` and `<UL>` `<LI>` tags then set height of `<LI>`

Comment: I am saying dropdown list height not dropdown height @Murtaza